# Multiple people fill out single Cognito form

Tags: cognito-forms

New to Cognito...I want to create a form so that each section is filled out by a different user.

Example:

1. User A fills out section 1 and sends form to User B
2. User B fills out section 2 and sends form to User C
3. User C fills out section 3 and sends form to Upper Management for approval

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with Cognito Forms.

While you can set this up using different Email Notification's to be sent out when a specific field has been filled out or a specific choice option has been selected. The user will be getting an edit link in their email and they will be able to make changes to the full form. We do not have a way to lock or restrict fields.

I think that our blog post on [workflow](http://blog.cognitoforms.com/how-to-build-multi-form-workflows) would help you the most in trying to set this up.

If you have other more specific questions please contact us via a [Help Request](https://www.cognitoforms.com/supportrequest/).